# Alternative to Teamviewer

Tags: teamviewer, alternative, open-source, free

I need an advise about alternative app for Teamviewer. For me is important to have such features like:

1. Ability to control PCs remotely
2. Switching sides to control each
   other PCs
3. Ability to talk in the meantime
4. Very easy to setup
5. Free and likely open-source

I checked all previous topics which were up here, but solutions are not in line with my requirements.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Splashtop ... used to be. X2Go – If you’re comfortable exposing your SSH port maybe run fail2ban with it. Mikogo – Surprisingly, not bad at all. To get it going you might need to

```
 sudo apt-get install libxtst6:i386
```

You could pay very reasonable price for Aeroadmin.